# AS3 AIR add 24 hours to timestamp

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying to add 24 hours to a timestamp which is generated with:

```
var date:Date = new Date();
var timeStamp:Number = date.time;
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just add 24 hours in milliseconds to the timestamp

```
timeStamp += 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000; //24 hours in milliseconds
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I didn't even think of that. I had in my mind there was a PHP INTERVAL equivalent...not sure why!